# Qt PostgreSQL foreign key issue

Tags: c++, sql, postgresql, qt

I've created a table which is called user_parameters in Qt Creator. While I was trying to give a reference to another table which is cities. I faced with a syntax error. My snippet for using foreign key and error are given bellow. How can I solve this error? Thx for your helping.

```
QSqlQuery query;
query.exec("CREATE TABLE user_parameters "
                  "(id SERIAL primary key, "
                  "firstname varchar(50), "
                  "lastname varchar(50), "
                  "age integer, "
                  "username varchar(50), "
                  "password varchar(100), "
                  "cityID integer references cities(id))");
```

---

```
QSqlQuery insertQuery;
int last_id = maxIdValue() + 1;

insertQuery.prepare("INSERT INTO user_parameters (id, firstname, lastname, age, username, password, cityID)"
                            "VALUES(:id, :firstname, :lastname, :age, :username, :password, :cityID)");

insertQuery.bindValue(":id", last_id);
insertQuery.bindValue(":firstname", fName);
insertQuery.bindValue(":lastname", lName);
insertQuery.bindValue(":age", age);
insertQuery.bindValue(":username", userName);
insertQuery.bindValue(":password", password);
insertQuery.bindValue(":cityID", cityID);
```

> QSqlError("42601", "QPSQL: Unable to create query", "ERROR:  syntax error at or near "("\nLINE 1: EXECUTE  (1, 'Name', 'Surname', 22, 'userName', 'password', 1)\n                 ^\n(42601)")

Comment: show us the query that fails, this error is not coming from the query you are showing us.

Comment: i added query part in the question

Comment: I suppose you've passed a database binding or login into. Also the issue might happen, if you execute it from separated (from QSqlDatabase object) thread. 
Please try to refer QSqlDatabase in QSqlQuery constructor as a parameter. QSqlQuery::QSqlQuery(QSqlDatabase db)

Answer (score 0):

your query looks ok to me , however you might be missing a space before "values" keyword.also two side notes :

1. serial is deprecated method of having identity column. use `generated as identity` instead.
2. serial/ identity columns are managed by sql engine, you can avoid getting max value and insert it each time.

so :

```
insertQuery.prepare("INSERT INTO user_parameters (firstname, lastname, age, username, password, cityID) "
                            "VALUES(:firstname, :lastname, :age, :username, :password, :cityID)");
```

notice the space at the end of first line

Comment: Thanks, i paid attention parts you mentioned, but i get the same error.
Can   cityID integer REFERENCES cities(id)   part be wrong or can something be missing in here?

Comment: @OnurKaraman no, as I mentioned your query looks ok , you should look for an issue outside the sql.

Comment: Thanks! The error was indeed outside of sql, my table creation function was causing this error.